# UnitofWork + DependencyResolver will raise an exception when calling .Save() "The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, unit-of-work

I am working on an asp.net mvc 5.2 web application + Entity framework 6. and i have defined 2 repositories for two entities; SecurityRole and Staff, then i defined a unit of work between them as follow:-

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private SkillManagementEntities context = new SkillManagementEntities();
        private SkillRepository skillRepository;
        private StaffRepository staffRepository;
        private SecurityRoleRepository securityroleRepository;
        private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
        private SkillVersionHistoryRepository SVH;
        private LinkToKBRepository linkToKBRepository;
        public SkillRepository SkillRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.skillRepository == null)
                {
                    this.skillRepository = new SkillRepository(context);
                }
                return skillRepository;
            }
        }

        public StaffRepository StaffRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.staffRepository == null)
                {
                    this.staffRepository = new StaffRepository(context);
                }
                return staffRepository;
            }
        }

        public SecurityRoleRepository SecurityRoleRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.securityroleRepository == null)
                {
                    this.securityroleRepository = new SecurityRoleRepository(context);
                }
                return securityroleRepository;
            }
        }

        public async Task Save()
        {
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

now inside the SecurityRole controller i have the following action method , to assign Staffs to security role:-

```
public class SecurityRoleController : Controller
    {

    UnitOfWork uniteofwork = new UnitOfWork(); 
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public async Task<ActionResult> AssignStaffsToSR(int? id , int[] selectedStaffsids)
        {


            var dbsecurityrole = new SecurityRole();
            try
            {

                dbsecurityrole = await uniteofwork.SecurityRoleRepository.FindSecurityRole(id.Value,sr=>sr.Staffs);
              uniteofwork.SecurityRoleRepository.UpdateSecurityRoleUsers(selectedStaffsids, dbsecurityrole);
              await uniteofwork.Save();
                TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} User/s have been Assigned", String.Empty);
                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return Json(new { ISsuccess = true });
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occured");
            }



                 return View(await uniteofwork.SecurityRoleRepository.populateAssignStaff(dbsecurityrole)); 
            }
```

which calls the following repository method:-

```
public class SecurityRoleRepository :  ISecurityRoleRepository , IDisposable
        {
         private SkillManagementEntities context;
         private IStaffRepository staffrepo = (IStaffRepository)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IStaffRepository));
         public SecurityRoleRepository(SkillManagementEntities context)
            {
                this.context = context;
            }
public void UpdateSecurityRoleUsers(int[] selectedUsers, SecurityRole securityRole)
              {
                  var dbSecurityRolestaffs = securityRole.Staffs.ToList();
                  var activestaffs = staffrepo.GetActiveStaff().ToList();

                  foreach (var s in activestaffs)
                  {

                      if (selectedUsers.Contains(s.StaffID))
                      {
                          if (!dbSecurityRolestaffs.Any(a => a.StaffID == s.StaffID))
                          {

                              securityRole.Staffs.Add(s);
                          }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          if (dbSecurityRolestaffs.Any(a => a.StaffID == s.StaffID))
                          {
                              securityRole.Staffs.Remove(s);
                          }



                      }
                  }

              }
```

and i have defined the following dependency resolver between the repositories:-

```
public class YourDependencyResolverClass : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public YourDependencyResolverClass()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }


    private void AddBindings()
    {
        kernel.Bind<ISkillRepository>().To<SkillRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IStaffRepository>().To<StaffRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ISecurityRoleRepository>().To<SecurityRoleRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ISkillVersionHistoryRepository>().To<SkillVersionHistoryRepository>();
     }
```

but currently when i call the `await uniteofwork.Save();` inside my action method i got the following exception:-

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
>   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

although i am using a UnitofWork class which should pass the same objectcontext between the repositories and entities ??

Answer (score 1):

UnitOfWork uniteofwork = new UnitOfWork(); -> Always create a connection, you should open connection when you need, dont use like that

```
using(UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork()){
    unitOfWork.YourRepository.DoStuff();
    unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

Maybe your problem here: `(IStaffRepository)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IStaffRepository));`
This will get StaffRepository for you and the context is different.

You can try to fix like this, but i'm not recommend this way because code is not good.

```
 private IStaffRepository staffrepo;
 public SecurityRoleRepository(SkillManagementEntities context)
 {
      this.context = context;
      staffrepo = new StaffRepository(context);
 }
```

Comment: so what is exactly the problem in myc ase ?

Comment: Use using block, when out of using block, will call dispose and release connection. In your case, you create connection and initialize field in controller, and keep that connection although maybe in some action You dont even use that connection. Because connection pool is limited, so use it and realease it for another. I saw you use IDisposable, but i wonder why you dont use "using" block or call dispose anywhere. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: but will this solve the "

    The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.
" error ?

Comment: and i think that asp.net mvc & Ef will automatically call the dispose method when closing the connection .. and i do not have to explicitly do this...

Comment: No, you must use using block for this case to realease connection imidiately .  Let's take an test about 100 users and you will see the problem. And about your case, i found problem is (IStaffRepository)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IStaffRepository));

Comment: The default behavior of DbContext is that the underlying connection is automatically opened any time is needed and closed when it is no longer needed. But we use using block to make sure when out of using(finished stuff) -> dispose immidiately. That's the way people did. And I updated your problem, take a try.

Comment: ok ur update worked well, but why you mentioned that  >>i'm not recommend this way because code is not good.<< ,, i mean why u do not recommend this ?